# How to handle a variable length number sequence with look behind assertion regex in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, regex

This question is slightly similar to others asked but I cannot get those fixes to work for me so here goes. I need to construct a regex that pulls out fill%s out of data of the form:

```
<Fill Ch="**Ch3**" DC="45059" MHP="19" />
<Fill Ch="**Ch2**" DC="33" MHP="100" />
```

Where the channel will be Ch1, Ch2, CH3 etc, the DC value is a variable length number sequence up to 5 digits, and `MHP="data"` is what I need to capture.

Currently I have the regex:

```
b'(?<=**Ch1**\"\sDC\=\")(?:\d|\d\d|\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d)\"\sMHP\=\"\d+'
```

Which handles the variable length data but includes it in the string leading to:

```
b'45059" MHP="100'
```

How do I remove the `DC` data and just preserve the `100` in this case? I need the first sequence as I need to specify Ch1, Ch2, Ch3 into different arrays.

Thanks, and sorry this is my first question.

Comment: Why not use a capturing group instead? `<Fill\s+Ch="Ch\d+"\s+DC="\d{1,5}"\s+MHP="(\d+)"\s+\/>`  https://regex101.com/r/YsaOCb/1

Comment: Because then it would work fine lol. I've only just started with regexes but your solution absolutely works.

Comment: Is all of the input data in the same format? If so you could use a simple `MHP=\"(\d+)\"` no need to overcomplicate it...

Answer (score 1):

If the key value pairs are in that order, you can use a match with a capturing group instead of using a lookbehind which is more flexible using `re`

```
<Fill\s+Ch="Ch\d+"\s+DC="\d{1,5}"\s+MHP="(\d+)"\s+\/>
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YsaOCb/1)

In parts

- `<Fill` Match the starting part
- `\s+Ch="Ch\d+"` 1+ whitespace chars, the key Ch and value for Ch being 1+ digits
- `\s+DC="\d{1,5}"` 1+ whitespace chars, the key DC= and the value being 1-5 digits *( here the alternation is shortened using a quantifier {1,5} )*
- `\s+MHP="` 1+ whitespace chars, then `MHP"`
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- = `"\s+\/>` Match the ending part

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

1. Your data stream is either `singular` **OR** `multiline` but with no other data

   ```
    <Fill Ch="**Ch3**" DC="45059" MHP="19" />
    <Fill Ch="**Ch2**" DC="33" MHP="100" />
   ```
2. You want to capture values for `Ch` and `MHP`
3. Data can be anything except a double quote

**RegEx**

```
Ch=\"(.*?)\".*?MHP=\"(.*?)\"
Ch=\"                           : Matches >> Ch="
     (                          : Start of first capture group
      .*?                       : Non-greedy capture anything until [next-character-in-string]
         )                      : Close of capture group
          \"                    : Matches the closing double quote which is [next-character-in-string]
            .*?                 : Non-greedy match consuming everything until the [next-required-match]
               MHP=\"           : Matches >> MHP=" which is [next-required-match]
                     (          : Start second capture group
                      .*?       : Non-greedy capture anything until [next-character-in-string]
                         )      : Close of second capture group
                          \"    : Matches the closing double quote which is [next-character-in-string]
```

**Working Example**

```
import re

regex    = r"Ch=\"(.*?)\".*?MHP=\"(.*?)\""

test_str = """
<Fill Ch="Ch3" DC="45059" MHP="19" /> <Fill Ch="Ch2" DC="33" MHP="100" />
"""

matches  = re.findall(regex, test_str)

// Output: matches == [('Ch3', '19'), ('Ch2', '100')]
```